# Spring-security авторизация через LDAP с получением дополнительных пользовательских данных

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap

Доброго времени суток!

Я новичок в spring.

**Описание:**

Мне нужно написать "закрытое" web-приложение с авторизацией пользователей через удалённый LDAP сервер и локальную базу данных MySQL.

У меня нет доступа к настройке LDAP сервера.

MySQL хранит все данные приложения включая список пользователей, допущенных к использованию системы, с правами и дополнительными параметрами.
Большинство этих параметров (фио, email, должность и т.д.) необходимо получить от LDAP сервера при успешной аутентификации пользователя.

Вот требования выдвигаемые к авторизации пользователей:

1. Индексная страница должна быть страницей входа.
2. Регистрация как таковая не предусмотрена (все пользователи должны иметь учётную запись на LDAP сервере и запись в таблице MySQL, которую добавляет администратор).
3. Пользователи на индексной странице вводят в форму свои рабочие учётные данные (логин, пароль). Затем, если сервер LDAP возвращает успешный ответ есть два варианта развития событий:

   3.1. Если пользователя с указанным логином не существует в таблице MySQL - он перенаправляется на страницу запроса доступа. Эта страница представляет собой форму, в которой пользователь может либо выйти, либо описать то, зачем ему нужен доступ к приложению. Далее запрос отобразится в админке и уже администратор будет решать, давать ли этому пользователю доступ к системе (и с какими правами) или нет.

   3.2. Если пользователь найден в таблице MySQL - он получает доступ к системе в соответствии со своими правами (указанными в другой таблице MySQL).
4. В будущем планируется добавить возможность авторизации пользователей через соц. сети по протоколу OAuth 2. Пользователь, единожды аутентированный через LDAP - может в своём личном кабинете привязать соц. сети и, в дальнейшем, авторизироваться через них не обращаясь к серверу LDAP.

**Вопросы:**

1. Если я правильно понял (поправьте, если не прав), на текущий момент
   spring - это код с минимумом xml (всё заменятся аннотациями и
   кодом), поэтому стараюсь писать код соответствующий нашему времени.
2. На данный момент я могу получить ответ от сервера LDAP при
   авторизации, но я не знаю, как получить дополнительные данные
   авторизованного пользователя.
3. Кроме того, не совсем понятно, как вмешаться в стандартный процесс авторизации и выполнять её по своему сценарию?
4. Как получить контроль над данными, хранящимся в сессии?
5. Где можно найти *адекватную* и, что немаловажно, *современную* документацию?

Пожалуйста, направьте меня на верный путь, в котором стоит копать.

Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вся актуальная информация по Spring находится по адресу [spring.io](https://spring.io/)
Для LDAP используем spring-ldap, для авторизации spring-security, чтобы все это крутилось в вебе - spring-mvc. Для входа в Spring советую книгу Крэйга Уолша "Spring в действии". Для получения доп. данных по пользователям из LDAP Вам как минимум нужна будет учётка с соответствующими правами на сервере.